# show/hide btns based on if there is a href path

Tags: javascript, html, json, hide, disable

I have a json file that is like this...

```
[
  {
    "id": "01",
    "image": "_img/speakers/2019/Abigail L.jpg",
    "organization": "Mumsnet",
    "name": "Abigail Lebrecht",
    "para": "Stopwords personalisation and Text cleaning at Mumsnet",
    "slides": "#"
  },

  {
    "id": "02",
    "image": "_img/speakers/2019/Alexis Iglauer.jpg",
    "organization": "PartnerRe",
    "name": "Alexis Iglauer",
    "para" : "Medical underwriting triage: An end-to-end machine learning case study",
    "slides": "assets/slides/Thurs 12 Sept/Stream 3 session 3/Alexis Iglauer.pptx"
  },

  {
    "id": "03",
    "image": "_img/speakers/2019/Amanda Beedham.jpg",
    "organization": "RSA Insurance",
    "name": "Amanda Beedham",
    "para": "Harnessing AI to Create Insight from Text",
    "slides": "assets/slides/Weds 11 Sept/Stream 3 session 2/AmandaBeedham_RSA.pptx"
  }
]
```

the file is actually much bigger than this but there are certain id's that have the slides key value set to `#....`

I am using JavaScript to inject a bunch of HTML into a web page that looks like this:

```
// get json file from directory
fetch("_img/speakers/speakers2019.json")
// store json data in res variable
.then(res => res.json())
// loop through json array and output mark up to target
// in index.html on line 447
.then(speakerArr => {

  var div = document.querySelector('.row_tile');
  for(var i = 0; i < speakerArr.length; i++) {
    div.innerHTML += `<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="hover-element member member-2" data-title-position="center,center">
      <div class="hover-element__initial">
        <img src="${speakerArr[i].image}" />
      </div>
      <div class="hover-element__reveal fade-transiton" data-overlay="9">
        <div class="boxed">
          <h6>${speakerArr[i].organization}</h6>
          <h5>${speakerArr[i].name}</h5>
          <p class="small-text">${speakerArr[i].para}</p>
          <a class="modalbutton" href="${speakerArr.slides}" download>Slides</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
  }
});
```

but this loop goes through the json and displays the button `<a class="modalbutton" href="${speakerArr.slides}" download>Slides</a>` for all entries in the json. The issue I have is that not all buttons have a link to be directed to; how can I modify this code so that it says ok everywhere the key/value is `#` don't display a button?

I have so far tried this:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < speakerArr.length; i++) {
    div.innerHTML += `<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="hover-element member member-2" data-title-position="center,center">
      <div class="hover-element__initial">
        <img src="${speakerArr[i].image}" />
      </div>
      <div class="hover-element__reveal fade-transiton" data-overlay="9">
        <div class="boxed">
          <h6>${speakerArr[i].organization}</h6>
          <h5>${speakerArr[i].name}</h5>
          <p class="small-text">${speakerArr[i].para}</p>
          if(speakerArr[i].slides === "#"){
            <a class="modalbutton" href="${speakerArr[i].slides}" download>Slides</a>
          } else {
            <a class="modalbutton disabled" href="${speakerArr[i].slides}" download>Unavailable</a>
          }
        </div>
      </div
    </div>
  </div>`;
  }
});
```

But this doesn't work as expected, how do we get the if/else inside the ``?

Ideally I'd like to not show a button for everywhere the key/value in the json is `#` how would that be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having another variable that has dynamic button to append:

```
var btn = ``;
for (var i = 0; i < speakerArr.length; i++) {

    if (speakerArr[i].slides === "#"){
        btn = `<a class="modalbutton" href="${speakerArr[i].slides}" download>Slides</a>`;
    } else {
        btn = `<a class="modalbutton disabled" href="${speakerArr[i].slides}" download>Unavailable</a>`;
    }

    div.innerHTML += `<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="hover-element member member-2" data-title-position="center,center">
      <div class="hover-element__initial">
        <img src="${speakerArr[i].image}" />
      </div>
      <div class="hover-element__reveal fade-transiton" data-overlay="9">
        <div class="boxed">
          <h6>${speakerArr[i].organization}</h6>
          <h5>${speakerArr[i].name}</h5>
          <p class="small-text">${speakerArr[i].para}</p>
          ${btn}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
}
```

**Update:**
Also, extending @Bek's answer, here is how you can use ternary operator

```
for (var i = 0; i < speakerArr.length; i++) {
    div.innerHTML += `<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="hover-element member member-2" data-title-position="center,center">
      <div class="hover-element__initial">
        <img src="${speakerArr[i].image}" />
      </div>
      <div class="hover-element__reveal fade-transiton" data-overlay="9">
        <div class="boxed">
          <h6>${speakerArr[i].organization}</h6>
          <h5>${speakerArr[i].name}</h5>
          <p class="small-text">${speakerArr[i].para}</p>
          ${speakerArr[i].slides == '#' ? `<a class="modalbutton" href="${speakerArr[i].slides}" download>Slides</a>` : `<a class="modalbutton disabled" href="${speakerArr[i].slides}" download>Unavailable</a>`}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly i just replaced the first btn condition with empty divs so no btn shows if there is nothing to link to.

Thanks a million man!!

Comment: I will after I understand where the ternary operator would go that BeK has responded with?

Comment: I have updated my answer with usage of ternanry operator.  Also, suggested update with question's headline.

Comment: Note: I have used conditions same as they are in your question. But, it seems you need if (speakerArr[i].slides != "#") rather than checking equals to "#" for a download button case . :)

Answer (score -1):

This should work in your case:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < speakerArr.length; i++) {
    div.innerHTML += `<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="hover-element member member-2" data-title-position="center,center">
      <div class="hover-element__initial">
        <img src="${speakerArr[i].image}" />
      </div>
      <div class="hover-element__reveal fade-transiton" data-overlay="9">
        <div class="boxed">
          <h6>${speakerArr[i].organization}</h6>
          <h5>${speakerArr[i].name}</h5>
          <p class="small-text">${speakerArr[i].para}</p>`;
          if(speakerArr[i].slides !== "#"){
            div.innerHTML += `<a class="modalbutton" href="${speakerArr[i].slides}" download>Slides</a>`;
          } 
        div.innerHTML += `</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using ternary operator like this:

```
`${speakerArr[i].slides == '#' ? '<a class="modalbutton" href="${speakerArr[i].slides}" download>Slides</a>' : '<a class="modalbutton disabled" href="${speakerArr[i].slides}" download>Unavailable</a>'}`
```

Comment: This looks good too, where would you place this? before the for loop executes? or inside the for loop?

Comment: @Nav definitely inside the for loop cos it need to execute for each iteration.